# What is going on? Contradictory results on the variance of random vector with random mean and covariance

Tags: probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose $f\mid\mu, F\sim N(\mu, F) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, where $\mu , F$ are both random (random vectors and random matrix respectively).

What is the correct way to derive $Var(f)$?

First, let $\tilde{f} = f - \mu$, I obtain:
\begin{align*}
    E[ff^T] &= E[(\tilde{f} + \mu)(\tilde{f} + \mu)^T]\\
                &= E[\tilde{f}\tilde{f}^T + \tilde{f} \mu^T + \mu \tilde{f}^T + \mu\mu^T]\\
                &= E[E[\tilde{f}\tilde{f}^T \mid \mu]] + 0 + E[\mu\mu^T]\\
                &= E[F] + E[\mu\mu^T]\\
                & = E[F]  + Var[\mu] +E[\mu]E[\mu]^T\\
\end{align*}

Approach 1:
\begin{align*}
Var(f) &= E[ff^T] - E[f]E[f]^T\\
&= E[ff^T] - E[E[f\mid\mu]] \quad E[E[f\mid\mu]]^T\\
&=E[ff^T] - E[\mu]E[\mu]^T\\
&= E[F] + Var(\mu)
\end{align*}

Approach 2:
\begin{align*}
Var(f) &= E[(f-\mu)(f-\mu)^T]\\
&= E[ff^T - f\mu^T - \mu f^T + \mu \mu^T]\\
&= E[ff^T] - E[E[f\mu^T\mid\mu]] - E[E[\mu f^T\mid\mu]] + E[\mu \mu^T]\\
&=E[ff^T] - E[\mu \mu^T]\\
&= E[ff^T] - Var(\mu) - E[\mu]E[\mu]^T\\
&= E[F]
\end{align*}

Approach 3:
\begin{align*}
Var(f) &= E[Var(f\mid F)] + Var(E[f\mid F])\\
&= E[F] + Var(\mu)\\
\end{align*}

This type of model is commonly used in Bayesian statistics, which one is the correct derivation? I feel like Approach 2 is since Appraoch 1 & 3 seems to miss one more expectation outside.

Similar confusion when deriving the covariance:

Approach 1:
\begin{align*}
Cov(a^T f, b^T f) &= E[a^Tff^T b] - E[a^Tf]E[b^Tf]\\
& = a^T E[ff^T] b - a^T E[f]E[f]^T b\\
&= a^T E[ff^T] b - a^T E[E[f\mid\mu]]E[E[f\mid\mu]]^T b\\
&= a^T E[ff^T] b - a^T E[\mu]E[\mu]^T b\\
&= a^T (E[F] + Var(\mu)) b\\
\end{align*}

Approach 2:
\begin{align*}
Cov(a^T f, b^T f) &= E[(a^Tf - E[a^T f]) (b^T f - E[b^T f])^T]\\
& = E[(a^Tf - a^T \mu) (b^T f - b^T \mu]T]\\
&= E[a^T(f-\mu)(f-\mu)^T b]\\
&= a^T E[E[ (f-\mu)(f-\mu)^T\mid F]] b\\
&= a^T E[F] b
\end{align*}

Comment: Just read the first sentence and stopped -- if $mu$ and $F$ are random, then the notation "$f \sim N(\mu, F)$" does not make sense and needs correction (this could be the source of  inconsistent results): it should be stated as $X | \mu = \mu_0, F = F_0 \sim N(\mu_0, F_0)$.

Answer (score 3):

"Approach 2" is incorrect. The very first expression
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(f) = E[(f - \mu)(f - \mu)^T]
\end{align}
is a mistake, because $\mu \neq E[f]$. In fact, $\mu$ is random while $E[f]$ (the unconditional expectation) is clearly non-random.  You should begin with the correct definition
$$\operatorname{Var}(f) = E[(f - E[f])(f - E[f])^T]$$
in Approach 2, which then reduces to Approach 1.

Your approach 1 and approach 3 are correct methods.

Comment: ahhhh right! Thanks. I deleted my previous comments to not confuse others